# Can't execute kubectl top nodes in amazon EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-eks

The scenario is simple to reproduce:

1. Create eks cluster with Role TempAdmin (we followed [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-cluster.html))
2. Configuring my credentials with TempAdmin, I can do:

```
    kubectl top nodes
```

3. The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html) says that the user/rol that created the cluster is automatically granted system:masters permissions. Create a new role (Admin) and grant system:masters permissions to that role:

```
$ kubectl get configmap -n kube-system aws-auth -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/EKS-Workers2-NodeInstanceRole-HWD4HSSO7NP1
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
      groups:
        - system:bootstrappers
        - system:nodes
    - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/Admin
      groups:
        - system:masters
kind: ConfigMap
...
```

4. Now, configuring my credentials to use the Admin role, I can do *almost* anything: I can create namespaces, edit aws-auth configmap, get nodes. However, when I try top nodes:

```
$ kubectl top nodes
Error from server (Forbidden): nodes.metrics.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot list nodes.metrics.k8s.io at the cluster scope: no RBAC policy matched
```

Adititonal info:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.2", GitCommit:"cff46ab41ff0bb44d8584413b598ad8360ec1def", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-01-10T23:35:51Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12+", GitVersion:"v1.12.10-eks-2e569f", GitCommit:"2e569fd887357952e506846ed47fc30cc385409a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-07-25T23:13:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: Do you have metrics server deployed?

Comment: Yes. With the original role (TempAdmin) I can do `kubectl top nodes`. With a new role in the group `system:masters` I get that error

Comment: Did you try adding username field and see whether that solves the issue? I.e. username: new-admin.

Comment: We don't have users in that account, we only have roles. Though I could try to create a user just to test that, we won't be having users in that account.

Comment: It is user within your kubernetes cluster, not an iam user. I undersand that you are using iam roles but maybe username block within your aws-auth configmap will solve the issue. I have a feeling that it will solve the problem.

Comment: Adding arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/Admin as the username value worked.Would you like to post the answer so I can accept it? The doc says "username: The user name within Kubernetes to map to the IAM role. By default, the user name is the ARN of the IAM role." Guess that's not always true :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the solution is to add username regardless of whether you are using IAM roles or IAM users in AWS. Mapping must be specified in your configmap otherwise that username will never be created in the kubernetes cluster and so it won’t be mapped to any permissions.

So you are missing username part in your newly added block to mapRoles.

Docs are a bit old in places and it is always good to be explicit in configmaps. This is at least something I usually try to follow.

I am happy you managed to make it work. :)